# How to release lock of file (camel exchange) to move it on exception (corrupted gz file)

Tags: apache-camel

I need to implement a handler that reacts on `ZipException` to move away corrupted gz files, otherwise the route will endlessly retry to unmarshal the gz.

The problem is that at the moment the exception is thrown there is a lock on this file (on linux `canWrite()` returns `false`) and there is the Camel lock file.

Is there an elegant Camel way to say/configure the `onException` that the lock is released (get write access and remove lockfile - if there is one)?

At the moment my code looks like that:

```
onException(ZipException.class)
    .handled(true)
    .process(corruptedFileProcessor)
    .stop();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following route reads gzipped files from srcDir, writes unzipped files to destDir (without the .gz extension) and when a ZipException occurs, sends the file to errorDir.

```
from("file://srcDir/?delete=true")
        .onException(ZipException.class)
        .handled(true).useOriginalMessage()
        .to("file://errorDir?autoCreate=true")
        .end()
.unmarshal().gzip()
.to("file://destDir?autoCreate=true&fileName=${file:name.noext}");
```